# REPtree algorithm output

Tags: weka, arff

Can anyone tell me how to interpret the output of REPtree algorithm under some kind of dataset.

Here is part if the output:

```
won < 36.5
|   team = BOS
|   |   year < 1961.5 : 36.6 (4/41.19) [1/3.06] 
|   |   year >= 1961.5
|   |   |   pace < 96.31 : 43.4 (2/1) [3/86]
|   |   |   pace >= 96.31 : 51.86 (3/2) [4/73]
|   team = CH1 : 20 (0/0) [1/913.28]
|   team = CL1 : 30 (1/0) [0/0]
|   team = DE1 : 40 (1/0) [0/0]
|   team = NYK
|   |   year < 1958
|   |   |   year < 1952.5 : 26.75 (3/1.56) [1/40.11]
|   |   |   year >= 1952.5 : 36.67 (2/0) [1/1]
|   |   year >= 1958 : 51.06 (12/91.24) [4/18.92]
|   team = PH1 : 36.89 (7/126.49) [2/15.44]
```

Comment: This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41867090/29771).

Answer (score 2):

I just found a good answer for you question. 
the number before : is the conditional rule.
the first number after : is the class value.
the first figures in both brackets, that's the number of instances matching the rule.
the second figures in both brackets, that's the percentage of instances misclassified by the rule.
[more reference, please see this link](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/about-REPtree-td15188.html)

Comment: can you explain a bit?

Comment: As @Marius says, can you put the important parts of the link here? Link-only answers aren't a good answer here.

Comment: Yes, I am just the beginner of English, So a little difficult to me write more ... Also thank you, I will try my best to improve it.